# @Async doesn't actually invoke method in another thread

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, concurrency

I have following code:

**main:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

In some place I have code like this:

```
public enum EmailMessage {
    ....
    void sendSilent(String from, String[] recipients, Map<String, ?> properties) {
            long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {

                emailService.sendEmail(from, this.subject, recipients, properties, this.templateFileName);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.warn("Could not send email", e);
            }
            finally {
                System.out.println("Result:" + (System.currentTimeMillis()- start)/1000 + " Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
}
```

Here I am setting **emailService**:

```
    @Service
    public static class EmailService {
        @PostConstruct
        public void initialize() {
            //to provide reference to EmailService to enum because enum could not be component
            EmailMessage.emailService = this;
        }
        ....
    }
```

**sendEmail:**

```
    @Async
    public void sendEmail(String from, String subject, String[] to, Map<String, ?> props, String templateFileName) throws Exception {
        .... //here some which executes slowly
        System.out.println( " sendEmail Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
   }
```

The code I provided produces following output:

```
 sendEmail Thread:1
Result:9 Thread:1
```

As you can see thread the same for both methods. And code executes 9 sec.

What do I wrong?

Comment: seems like your problem is here `EmailMessage.emailService = this;` you are bypassing the spring proxies this way somehow as far as I can tell. why is that an enum is *beyond* me, it should really be a plain class there

Comment: you're entire set-up is somehow disturbing, do you have any reason to use that enum in the first place? Also `System.currentTimeMillis()` should be replaced with `System.nanoTime`

Comment: @Eugene current design require to use enum and I could not change it. I think It doesn't matter System.currentTimeMillis() or  System.nanoTime at my case

Comment: you seems to create a local instance of the service. then there is nothing that would do the async invocation itself. you should use @ Component or @ Configuration wiring as [in the doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

Comment: in this case you should really search for a method to wire the bean into the enum

Comment: @gstackoverflow putting this can of logic into enum is imho bad design (is there any particular reason?) Still you can invoke the method asynchronously by yourself with executorService.invoke(..) . But the real solution would be fixing the design and putting the logic into beans (where the auto-wiring will work)